# Duda sobre construcción de una String

Tags: java, android, string, url, querystring

Buen día, tengo una duda que espero me puedan ayudar a resolver y es la siguiente:

Tengo las siguientes variables tipo String:

```
public static final String SERVER_PROTOCOL = "server.protocol";
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "server.address";
public static final String SERVER_PORT = "server.port";
```

Y tengo esta otra String "SERVER_URL"donde uno las 3 anteriores

```
public static final String SERVER_URL =  Config.getInstance().getProperty(Config.SERVER_PROTOCOL) + "://"+
        Config.getInstance().getProperty(Config.SERVER_ADDRESS)+":"+
        Config.getInstance().getProperty(Config.SERVER_PORT);
```

Lo que no entiendo es por que cuando depuro SERVER_URL es igual a "Http//54.157.123.154:80"

Es la primera vez que veo algo de este tipo, hasta el momento no he investigado nada por que no se que buscar en Google, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Estás concatenando el valor de las propiedades en tu configuración, usando Config.getInstance().getProperty. ¿Qué intentas obtener?

Comment: Hola Pablo, pues mira este código no es mio, estoy tratando de transcribirlo pero no entiendo por que String SERVER_PROTOCOL = "server.protocol" es igual a "Http" cuando ya tiene asignada la cadena "server.protocol",¿ en donde se configura que "server.protocol" es igual a "http"'

Comment: Te devuelve la direccion IP y el puerto 'el 80 corresponde a transferencia de documentos de hipertexto HTTP'.

Comment: Obtienes eso porque le pasas cada constante al método `getProperty` el cual devuelve:  el `server.protocol`,  el `server.address`  y el `server.port` de la instancia actual  obtenida con el método `getInstance` de la clase `Config`. El protocolo en este caso es `Http//`, la dirección es `54.157.123.154` y el puerto es `80`. Por cierto, el código se puede quizá optimizar, para no tener que obtener la instancia en cada llamada con `Config.getInstance()...`